# Wordpress: How to hook the crop in media editor

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm trying to hook the crop action on the image editor because I need to get the crop parameters in the image editor to use them after. 
But since the crop is performed by the image-edit.js, I can't figure out how I can perform this.
Is there a specific hook for that?

**EDIT**

I found the crop data are sent to wp-admin/includes/image-edit.php in the $_REQUEST array and the value of the crop is contained in $_REQUEST['history']
I'm trying to get this value, but every time i run it my function break the save process and I don't get any value in the custom field.

I'm trying with this:

```
add_action( 'wp_save_image_editor_file', 'custom_wp_save_image_editor_file');
function custom_wp_save_image_editor_file($saved, $filename, $image, $mime_type, $post_id ){
    update_field('crop_data', $_REQUEST['history'], $post_id); 
    return $saved;
}
```

but it doesn't work

**EDIT 2**
I'm using Advanced Custom Field so the update for the field was different. 
Now the action works only with a fixed value for $post_id (next step get post id for the attachment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my final solution to save the crop data in a ACF named `crop_data`.
I hope it could be useful for somebody...

```
add_action( 'wp_save_image_editor_file', 'save_crop_data');
function save_crop_data(){
    $attachment_id = $_REQUEST['postid'];
    $parent = get_post_ancestors($attachment_id);
    $post_id = $parent[0];
    update_field('crop_data', $_REQUEST['history'], $post_id);
    return $saved;
}
```